# Why Clementine was helping Kajit

Tags: overlord

In both anime and manga, Clementine (the crazy girl) helped Kajit (the priest) by bringing corpses and also bringing Enfrea (The boy) and even the item that she used Enfrea for   (I forgot the name of it).

Why did she do that?

I mean whatever she needed, she could just steal Enfrea and use that item on him if she liked.